# Tablebody is cleared way before the setInterval is called

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, setinterval

```
let datas = [
  ["14:01", "FRANKFRUIT", "FR402", "B02", "ONTIME"],
  ["15:22", "TOKYO", "TK211", "A32", "DELAYED"],
  ["15:35", "TOKYO", "GA90", "F89", "CANCELLED"],
  ["16:00", "OMAN", "NA15", "H64", "ONTIME"],
  ["17:35", "OMAN", "ZZ30", "N90", "ONTIME"],
];

//td and div generator

function wait(){

function rows(n,b) {
  for (i of datas[n]) {
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    let charr = i.split("");
    charr.forEach((e, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
        let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.newDiv');
        newDiv.innerHTML = e;
        //newDiv.classList.add("flip");
        td.appendChild(newDiv);
      }, 100*i);
     });
      Trow[b].appendChild(td);
    };
  };
  Tbody[0].textcontent = '';

random();

//randomising logic
function random(){
  for(let i = arr.length-1; i>0; i--){
    let randomval = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[randomval];
    arr[randomval] = temp;
  }
}

let Rows = [rows(arr[0],0), rows(arr[1],1), rows(arr[2],2), rows(arr[3],3), rows(arr[4],4)];

}
setInterval(function(){wait()},3000);
```

Guys, first of all, I am just a beginner. I want to clear the table body (Tbody[0].textcontent = '';) just before the set interval of 3 seconds so that I can append the next upcoming TD's but currently, it's cleared way before the set interval is called is there any way by which I can show it just before the setInterval is called? Also thank you in advance.